# Microsoft Access change default font?

Tags: microsoft-access

Today My Access got changed from Arial to MSPGothic (a font for display Japanese), How could I config to make Access show data as "Arial / Tahoma" again?

[image: Default font is MSGothic]
[image: File/Options/Datasheet/Default font has no option to change font]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Font control found within the Text Formatting panel of the ribbon shown in your first screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I only affect the `current` windows of Access, if I close Access and reopen the database again, it still got changed to MSPGothic again. (my question is how to change `default` font)